# Using multiple update or inner join is better for performance

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have the following update statement I use in trigger that have same behavior and both of it is correct but 2nd one have problem if I update both tableA_ID and ValueB at same times. But this not big issue as there is work around but if possible I want to avoid it. So what I want to know is there a big performance between this 2 and it will make me decide which one to go. If 2nd much better in performance than I will use 2nd one. But if the difference not that big I will use 1st one. I not expert in sql server. Anyone can help?

```
        UPDATE tableA
        SET tableA.Value = tableA.Value - old.ValueB
        FROM tableA
        INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT tableA_ID ,ValueB
                        FROM deleted
                    ) old ON old.tableA_ID = tableA.ID

        UPDATE tableA
        SET tableA.Value = tableA.Value + new.ValueB
        FROM tableA
        INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT tableA_ID ,ValueB
                        FROM inserted
                    ) new ON new.tableA_ID = tableA.ID
```

```
        UPDATE tableA
        SET tableA.Value = tableA.Value - old.ValueB + new.ValueB
        FROM tableA
        INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT tableA_ID ,ValueB
                        FROM deleted
                    ) old ON old.tableA_ID = tableA.ID

        INNER JOIN (
                        SELECT tableA_ID ,ValueB
                        FROM inserted
                    ) new ON new.tableA_ID = tableA.ID
```

Comment: Why do you need to write a trigger (an important point you did not mention) to do this? Why does the value of the column "Value" (which is a confusing name that you seem to have obfuscated)? And your join logic looks wrong - which is far more concerning.

Comment: @SMor Sorry for the naming. As for join I make some adjustment but for now is working just fine. As why I need to use trigger because this trigger is at tableB. Column value at tableA is sum of all valueB with same tableA_ID from tableB. The logic here is that I only insert data to tableB and the total value will be handle by trigger to update it in tableA. I also add some more info hopefully it is clear.

Answer (score 0):

As with anything, test it to be sure.

Whether or not you should be doing this in a trigger is a long discussion.

Performance-wise, you're going to see better performance, in most circumstances, with the second query. The reason I can simply state that is that you're only looking at a single lookup for the UPDATE in the query where you update everything all at once. Whereas, the first query has to find the data to UPDATE, two times.

However, again, test this.

And yes, as @SMor says in the comments, why you need this as a trigger should absolutely be discussed. Triggers can be seriously misused and abused.

Comment: Mention reply at @SMor as why I need trigger and also add some more info as why I need to choose. Testing this unfortunately I only able to test this in my local but I cannot test it in live server since I cannot simply edit any data as I want. I also thinking the 2nd one is better but is there big difference in performance?

Comment: The only way to know for sure is to test it. However, yes. I stand by what I said.